# how to push only one changed file

Tags: git, heroku, git-commit, heroku-cli

So, i have python app on heroku with some “database.db” when the app is running this database is filling up.

For example i have this files in my project:

```
bot.py
database.db
```

when i make changes in bot.py and trying to push changes, my database is refreshing and when updates are deployed it already cleared.

i using this algorithm to push changes:

```
heroku login
cd %dir%
git add .
git commit -am “commit”
git push heroku master
```

so how to push only bot.py changes, without touching database?

Comment: You need to stage only `bot.py` file.

Comment: Or you can add database.db to .gitignore

Answer (score 0):

Try `git add bot.py` instead of `git add .`

`git add .` will stage all the file in the present directory .

As you are asking to add the `bot.py` only specify the name of the file `bot.py`.

And

`git commit -m “commit”` instead of `git commit -am “commit”`.

Here remove the flag `-a`. Else it will commit everything.

**updated one**

```
heroku login
cd %dir%
git add bot.py
git commit -m “commit”
git push heroku master
```

Comment: `git commit -am “commit”` he also wrote that. The `-a` flag commits everything. He needs to remove that.

Comment: thanks @TinNguyen . i have just noticed that and updated my ans also. thanks again